# Rviz, slam_gmapping hangs

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am having some troubles with Rviz recently, my computer will hangs suddenly while i am using it. Originally it works fine and it is only recently that I got this problem. Does anyone have any idea what is going on? I know that my question sound really vague and lack information, but what I can deduced is my system hangs when I am using Rviz.

My graphic card is GeForce 9300M GS. Driver Version : 304.84. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.  ROS fuerte. My Rviz revision number is 1.8.17.

Another thing is, this happened when I am using the 2dnav goal setting function on Rviz. And I think Rviz seems to be unable to receive  message from  robot footprint and obstacle. I am thinking it might have something to do with cost map or laser/odom input. Just a guess.

Any feedback will be appreciated. Thank you.

Update 1

At the point where it hangs, slam_mapping take up 12% of CPU but used up 1.2 GiB of memory.

After my system recovered from hanging, Rviz takes like 60-70 % of CPU abd used up like 100 plus MIB of memory.And I can no longer find slam_gmapping in the list of process in the system monitor. Yet it appears when I do rosnode list.

After the system recovered from hanging, I can't get any messages from move_base/local_costmap node.

In addition, I got this message on my terminal :

```
[ WARN] [1363349588.818795860, 121.587000000]: Could not get robot pose,  
cancelling reconfiguration
[ERROR] [1363349591.052922982, 121.887000000]: Extrapolation Error looking up 
robot pose: Unable to lookup transform, cache is empty, when looking up transform 
from frame [/base_footprint] to frame [/map]
```

A little background on what I am doing, I actually sort of alter the URDF so that the robot's sensors experience some pitching and rolling in motion, so I guess the input to slam_gmapping and costmap is affected. But previously such issue did not happened even after i altered the URDF.

Update 2:

Result from roswtf

```
Online checks summary:

Found 2 warning(s).
Warnings are things that may be just fine, but are sometimes at fault

WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:
 * /move_base_node/local_costmap/voxel_grid_throttle:
   * /move_base_node/local_costmap/voxel_grid
 * /move_base_node:
   * /move_base_simple/goal
   * /move_base/cancel
 * /voxel_visualizer:
   * /move_base_node/local_costmap/voxel_grid_throttled
 * /gazebo:
   * /gazebo/set_link_state
   * /set_hfov
   * /gazebo/set_model_state
   * /set_update_rate

WARNING These nodes have died:
 * spawn_robot-5
 * slam_gmapping-11


Found 11 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/robot_state_publisher] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/slam_gmapping] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/point_cloud_to_laser_manager] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/voxel_visualizer] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/base_laser_self_filter] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/rviz_1363420915715223896] raised an error: 
ERROR Communication with [/robot_pose_ekf] raised an error: 
ERROR Could not contact the following nodes:
 * /slam_gmapping

ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:
 * /robot_state_publisher->/robot_pose_ekf (/tf)
 * /robot_pose_ekf->/base_laser_self_filter (/tf)
 * /gazebo->/slam_gmapping (/base_scan/scan)
 * /gazebo->/slam_gmapping (/clock)
 * /robot_state_publisher->/base_laser_self_filter (/tf)
 * /robot_state_publisher->/slam_gmapping (/tf)
 * /slam_gmapping->/robot_pose_ekf (/tf)
 * /robot_pose_ekf->/slam_gmapping (/tf)
 * /robot_pose_ekf->/robot_pose_ekf (/tf)
 * /slam_gmapping->/base_laser_self_filter (/tf)
 * /gazebo->/slam_gmapping (/tf)
 * /slam_gmapping->/slam_gmapping (/tf)

ERROR Errors connecting to the following services:
 * service [/slam_gmapping/tf_frames] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to   
communicate with service [/slam_gmapping/tf_frames], address    
[rosrpc://ubuntu:48043]
 * service [/slam_gmapping/set_logger_level] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable 
to communicate with service [/slam_gmapping/set_logger_level], address 
[rosrpc://ubuntu:48043]

* service [/dynamic_map] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to communicate with  
service [/dynamic_map], address [rosrpc://ubuntu:48043]
* service [/slam_gmapping/get_loggers] appears to be malfunctioning: Unable to   
communicate with service [/slam_gmapping/get_loggers], address 
[rosrpc://ubuntu:48043]

ERROR TF multiple authority contention:
 * node [/robot_pose_ekf] publishing transform [/base_footprint] with parent   
[/odom] already published by node [/gazebo]
 * node [/gazebo] publishing transform [/base_footprint] with parent [/odom]  
already published by node [/robot_pose_ekf]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58129/rviz,-slam_gmapping-hangs/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-03-14**:
Please provide your RViz version and graphics card model.
Another thing you could check is if RViz is filling up your memory, which would point to a memory leak.

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2013-03-14**:
How do I check if Rviz is filling up my RAM?

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-03-14**:
Recently I got a similar problem several times: Totally unresponsive WLAN and/or RViz, maybe in correlation with kinect pointcloud or navigation's potential map..

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-03-14**:
You can use Ubuntu's system monitor to check the memory usage of running programs.

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2013-03-15**:
Please refer to my update 1.

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-03-15**:
Seems more like slam_gmapping is causing your problem, not rviz.
rosnode list might show you nodes that have already crashed, in that case roswtf will give you the right information.

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2013-03-15**:
Hmmm... I did roswtf and i think i sort of have some idea about what's wrong.

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2013-03-15**:
All right. Found the source of my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi peers. Found the source of my error. It is due to me running the robot_pose_ekf package that produce an additional source of /base_link to /odom transformation. This contradict with the transformation produced by Gazebo. After removing the robot_pose_ekf, things went back to normal.

Thanks for all the advices !!!

---

Originally posted by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) with karma: 201 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We had a similar problem and the reason was that VSYNC was enabled for the Nvidia graphic. Running nvidia-settings and disabling VSYNC solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) with karma: 1339 on 2013-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2013-03-14**:
Thanks for the reply TommyP. Did you encounter the problem suddenly? For my case, it was originally fine but it just failed to work for no reason suddenly. May I also know when did you encounter this problem?

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2013-03-14**:
I did what you mentioned. It doesn't seems to help.